# finding loops with a specific lenght in a large graph

Tags: matlab

I am going to find efficiently all loops with length 4 in a large graph.I have the following code for this purpose but it is not efficient.

```
[rows, cols, s] = find(Mystructure);
for i = 1:size(cols,1)
a = rows(i);
b = cols(i);
C=cols(find(rows==b));
 for j=1:size(C)
   c=C(j);
   D=cols(find(and(rows==c, rows~=a)));
   for k=1:size(D)
   d=D(k);
   if(d~=a && d~=b)
   if(find(and(rows==d, cols==a)))
       FourStructure=[FourStructure;a b c d] ;
   end
   end
   end
  end
end
```

Mystructure is a sparse matrix representing my graph. Mystructure(i,j) is one if and only if i,j be connected.

Comment: You should post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I haven't read your code, it's quite unreadable. As a starting point - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal ?

Comment: You can use logical indexing instead of find, e.g. the last `find` can be replaced by `any`: `if(any(and(rows==d, cols==a)))`.